# Make particular column as combo box of DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I just want to make Data Grid. Where first and second column of data grid is for storing single value and third column as combo box.

The code that i tried is

```
    Dim productGrid As New DataGridView        
    ProductGrid.Columns(0).Name = "CB"
    ProductGrid.Columns(1).Name = "ProductGroup"
    ProductGrid.Columns(2).Name = "Product"
    Dim i As Integer
    With ProductGrid
        If .Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        i = 1
        Dim objValueItems As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        objValueItems.Items.Add("Server")
        objValueItems.Items.Add("Standalone")
        objValueItems.Items.Add("Demo")
        objValueItems.Items.Add("Anywhere")
        ProductGrid.Item(2, i).Value = objValueItems
    End With
```

I am getting the error on "ProductGrid.Item(2, i).Value = objValueItems" this line. Error is " Index was out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that all the cells of a `ComboBox DGV Column` have the same contents, thus you are not assigning a list of items to a given cell, but to all of them (to a column). You have to include this when adding the given column. Sample code:

```
Dim productGrid As New DataGridView
With productGrid
    .Columns.Add("CB", "CB") 'Text-type column
    .Columns.Add("ProductGroup", "ProductGroup")  'Text-type column
    Dim objValueItems As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    With objValueItems
        .Name = "Product"
        .Items.Add("Server")
        .Items.Add("Standalone")
        .Items.Add("Demo")
        .Items.Add("Anywhere")
    End With
    .Columns.Add(objValueItems) 'ComboBox-type column
End With
```